# Is it possible to add content to <head> from <body> in PHP

Tags: php, html

I'd like to know if it is possible to add content to the `<head>` section of HTML from the `<body>`, in PHP.

I know how to do this in JQuery, but I need to the final HTML code to already have the aditional data.

I also know that I can use `ob_start()` to manage all the content that will be processed, but the reason I'm asking this is because I have some websites already finalized and wanted to know if there is a simpler way to do this, instead of restructure the entire website (and it isn't just one, there are several).

Just for explain better, usually my websites are structured like this:
 - I have a "`master page`", who have all the content there are present in the whole site (like header, footer, etc), kind of like this (it's not this simple - I use validation, friendly URLs, etc - it's for example only):

```
<?php
  $page = $_GET['page'];
  <html>
  <head>
    // All my header content
  </head>
  <body>
    if($page == 'home')
      include('pages/home.php');
    elseif($page == 'about')
      include('pages/about.php');
  // etc
  // Here comes my footer content
 </body>
</html>
?>
```

Bottom of line: I want to add content to the `<head>` from some of the pages included.

Since now, thank's for all help.

Comment: You mixed up PHP & HTML. Where are your PHP tags?

Comment: I know, the code was just for illustration. Don't mind it.

Comment: Not restrospectively. PHP evaluates line by line, you'd need to do some logic before you start outputting anything to determine whether the data needs to be added to the head section. This is another reason why MVC frameworks and/or templating are a good idea.

Comment: most of us to all the processing logic, before outputting a single line of html, makes life easier.

Comment: First of all your using the PHP tags `<?php ?>` in the wrong way. Puting HTML code inside it will create an error.

What does the header content sample look like?

Comment: http://php.about.com/od/learnphp/qt/php_with_html.htm..This might help you understand

Comment: Hey guys, thank's you all for your attention. About the wrong use of the tags, as I said before, the code in the post are just for illustration. They're not as I really use them. About using frameworks, I developed one of my own recently, but I'm asking this to have a quick solution for this situation, while I get every old site of mine adapted to this framework (where this situation was already solved, by using buffer management).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can look at the concept of the code below. What you really want is not clear for me so you can add comment if ever.

```
<?php
    $msg = "<script> function TryOpen(){ alert('Hello World!'); } </script>";
?>
<html>
<head>
    <?php echo $msg; ?>
</head>
<body>
    <?php
        if($page == 'home')
            include('pages/home.php');
        elseif($page == 'about')
            include('pages/about.php');
    ?>
    <input type="button" name="btnAlert" value="Click" onclick="TryOpen();" />
</body>
</html>
```

For I have no idea what kind of content you want in the `<head>` tag so I made a script for an example. Hope it can somehow help.

Comment: Hey Juan, thank's for your attention. What I really need is: some of the pages being included in <body> are, for example, News (where the content are added from a Admin page). Which means, the content in the News page are dynamic. I want to add to the <head> Facebook tags, which changes for every news loaded. Got it?

Comment: I see. Since the content is dynamic depending on something (you said "which changes for every news loaded"). Use a variable for that. Like in may code above. I made a sample `$msg` variable. Use that logic to satisfy your criteria.

Comment: Juan, thanks again for your help. I thought about that, but I was thinking if there'd be some way more "right". I'm trying some options here, and I'll post the results later. Thanks.